# Control the limit of database results on a php page using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Is there anyway to control the limit of entries from a database using jquery.

---

I have the PHP `Data.php`:

```
mysqli_query($con,"(select * from social order by id desc limit 30) order by id asc");
```

---

But I want to be able to edit the `limit 30` and use `$.get()` to request the php again on calling a click function in jquery. Is this possible?

---

The `$.get()`:

```
 $.get("Data.php", function (data3) {
     $(".data").html(data3);
 });
```

---

## My code now looks like this:

### `Data.php`:

```
$limit_amt = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['limit']);

$result = mysqli_query($con,"(select * from social order by id desc limit ".$limit_amt.") order by id asc");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
      echo "<tr class='border_bottom'>";
      echo "<th scope='col'>";
      echo "<div align='left'><span class='name'>".$row['name']."</span></div><br />";
      echo "<span class='text'>".$row['comunicate']."</span><br />";
      echo "<div align='right'><span class='time'>".$row['date']."</span></div>";
      echo "</th>";
      echo "</tr>";

  }
```

### `Index.php`:

```
$.get("Data.php",{ limit: 40}, function (data3) { .
         $(".data").html(data3);

    });
```

Comment: Unclear, need more code. Do you mean you want a dynamic value in place of  `30`? Also what's your current `$.get()` code?

Comment: Would you like anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `$.get()`:

```
//#btn would represent an HTML element like <input type="button" id="btn">
$("#btn").click(function(e){
    // I have given a static value here but you can change it to a variable or 
    // however you want to pass
    $.get("Data.php",{ limit: 40}, function (data3) { .
         $(".data").html(data3);
    });
}
```

In your `Data.php`:

```
//Fetching the value and saving into a variable
$limit_amt = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['limit']);
//Using the fetched value to change the limit amount
mysqli_query($con,"(select * from social order by id desc limit ".$limit_amt.") order by id asc");
```

Comment: There is also a `Write-to.php` page which sends the data (The data that `Data.php` receives) is that a problem?

Comment: Do you mean `Write-to.php` is also having a `$.get()` function call to `Data.php`? If so, that's not a problem, you can have multiple `$.get()` requests to the same file, just remember to use different parameter names.

Comment: I mean basically. How is `$_GET['limit']` getting `limit:40` it seems strange. Would this work on $document.ready? I am also getting 2 errors: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given. And mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given.

Comment: Please look at my updated question I have shown you what my full code looks like

Comment: Can you try `$result = mysqli_query($con,"(select * from social order by id desc limit {$limit_amt}) order by id asc");` ?  The second error is probably related to the first failed query.  Also, this line: `$limit_amt = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['limit']);`

Comment: I am still getting: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: Your query seems to be failing. Can you try `echo mysqli_error($con);` after `mysqli_query`? Alternatively you could try the actual query on your phpMyAdmin if you have access.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') order by id asc' at line 1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47622/discussion-between-i-can-has-cheezburger-and-maximilian)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but why isn't this working? `var load = 20;
$("#loadmore").click(function() {
  var load = load + 20;
  $.get("Data.php",{ limit: load}, function (dataa) {
                     $(".data").html(dataa);   
                });
});`

Comment: That's because you are declaring load variable twice, try: `var load = 20;
     $("#btn").click(function () {
         var load1 = load + 20;
         $.get("test2.php", {
             limit: load1
         }, function (dataa) {
             $(".data").html(dataa);
         });
     });`

Comment: Can you please click on the above chat link again?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some mistake in the query that you have used

please try

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"(select * from social order by id desc limit ".$limit_amt.")");
```

instead of

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"(select * from social order by id desc limit ".$limit_amt.") order by id asc");
```